# How do I create a code so that c in c^2 = a^2 + b^2 is the longest side after typing in the command-line arguments in Java?

Tags: java

**The instruction**
Integers and booleans. Write a program RightTriangle that takes three int command-line arguments and determines whether they constitute the side lengths of some right triangle.
right triangle
The following two conditions are necessary and sufficient:

*Each integer must be positive.
*The sum of the squares of two of the integers must equal the square of the third integer.

My Attempt:

```
public class RightTriangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        boolean arePositive;
        arePositive = (a >=0) && (b>=0) && (c>=0);
        boolean isRightTriangle;
        isRightTriangle =(c*c == b*b + a*a) && arePositive;
        System.out.println(isRightTriangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Math.max(Math.max(a,b),c)` to find the largest value.

Comment: It still gives false when you type 13 5 12 in the command line, which shouldn't be case because 13 5 12 do make a right angled triangle. I'm kinda new to programming and this is a tutorial we were given at school.

Comment: The last command-line argument shouldn't always correspond to the longest side

Answer (score 2):

My logic will be to examine whether the numbers are positive, that is the first thing to do. You then determine which of the input arguments is the hypotenuse by examining which is the largest of the three numbers. Whether it is the smallest or the medium is not very important, both the medium and the smallest will be the legs. After that, you examine whether the condition c ^ 2 = a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 is met and cross it with the condition that the input is positive, thus closing all required options.

Test: cs>java RightTriangle.java 13 12 5, result shoud be --> TRUE!

```
public class RightTriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
        int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); 
    
        boolean arePositive = (a >=0) && (b>=0) && (c>=0);
        
        int min    = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
        int max    = Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
        int median = a + b + c - min - max;
        
        boolean isRightTriangle = (max*max == min*min + median*median) && arePositive;
        
        System.out.println(isRightTriangle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you map the `String` array `args` to an `integer` array `sides`, you can just sort the values, ensuring that the largest value will be in the last element of the array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RightTriangle{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] sides = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
        Arrays.sort(sides);
        
        int a = sides[0];
        int b = sides[1];
        int c = sides[2];
        
        System.out.println(sides);
        boolean arePositive = (a >=0) && (b>=0) && (c>=0);
        boolean isRightTriangle = (c*c == b*b + a*a) && arePositive;
        System.out.println(isRightTriangle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to keep the highest value in `c`.

```
public class RightTriangle {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            int c = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(args[2]);
            int b = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(args[1]);
            int a = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(args[0]);
            System.out.println(isRightTriangle(a * a, b * b, c * c));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public static boolean isRightTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        return (a + b == c || a + c == b || b + c == a);
    }
}
```